# Groups Controller could not be found

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

I am making the admin portion of my CakePHP project. I have successfully made the login-logout module. Now I am making a module named "Users Groups" in which I am listing the different groups of users. For that I have made a `GroupsController.php` file. But when I load the URL as localhost/testblog/groups, I get this error:

```
Error: GroupsController could not be found.

Error: Create the class GroupsController below in file:
```

admin\Controller\GroupsController.php

```
<?php
class GroupsController extends AppController {
}

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create admin\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp
```

Please can anyone tell me the solution? I have searched a lot but could not get it.

Comment: i have followed the conventions as of cakephp and also put the GroupsController.php file under localhost/testblog/admin/controller/ directory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file name should be groups_controller.php